# EDATE, MAXIF Leap Year for last year calc

Tags: excel, if-statement, maxifs

For this example, The max date in column D is 2/28/2021. I'm trying to return the EOM value for the prior year which would be 2/29/2020 but instead this is returning 2/28/2020. What do I need to change for it to capture the leap year and always bring the last day of the month?

```
=EDATE(MAXIFS(D:D,H:H,12),-12)
```

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/year-is-a-leap-year
hope this help you

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I'm still a bit confused. I need the MAX DATE in column D. If the MAX DATE is 2/28/2021, I need a way to identify the sum for the last year's sale, in this case, 2/29/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my error. I needed to EOMONTH instead of EDATE